# Debian update failed

Tags: ubuntu

I am getting is issue

```
Err:19 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05 NO_PUBKEY FEEA9169307EA071
```

when try to update debian. Any suggestion or idea is there how to fix the issue.

Comment: What is the Debian version you are trying to update? What steps have you taken to update?

Comment: I see absolutely no research effort.

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386186/do-questions-have-to-restate-all-implications-of-supplied-content-to-be-acceptab).

Answer (score 22):

Try:

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/known-issues#keyexpired-2